# What help does the standard library offer for drawing and manipulating basic shapes?

Tags: ios, swift, core-graphics

I'd like to add basic image annotation to an app that allows users to do the following:

- draw a shape (not freeform shapes, only circle, rect, arrow)
- tap the shape to bring up controls for scaling and translating the shape
- store the shape as archived NSData to be editable again later

I'm having a difficult time figuring out what parts of this are already there so I don't go reinventing the wheel with `CAShapeLayer` and the like to draw, manipulate, and store the shapes.

Which parts of Core Graphics or Cocoa should I read into?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enough to use UIKit, concretely:

- CAShapeLayer
- UIBezierPath
- UIView
- and needed components

Next you can store it in NSFileManager or NSUserDefaults.